# mv: cannot move No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, mv

I'm trying to move a file but keep getting

mv: cannot move ‘artifacts/lfaa-2.11.0-LFD-BR-SNAPSHOT.zip’ to ‘artifacts/applyadmin-ase/bab/BAB.2.11.0-11.zip’: No such file or directory

```
        sh "mv artifacts/lfa*.zip \"artifacts/applyadmin-${updatedVersion}-${BUILD_NUMBER}.zip\""
```

these are the values of the variables

version= ase/bab/BAB

BUILD_NUMBER= 2.11.0.7

Comment: That means the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @CherryDT file exists

Comment: And `artifacts/applyadmin-ase/bab/` exists too?

Comment: decided to replace the forward slash characters with - in the destination path.